Maximizing a region using jQuery
I have an interactive grid region in oracle apex that I want to be able to maximize via a toggle button located on the far right side of the toolbar.  The customization of the toggle button itself has been relatively straightforward but I am struggling with how to implement the maximize function.  I included the code I have so far that is located in the interactive grid's "Initialization JavaScript Function" section.


function(config) {
    let $           = apex.jQuery,
    toolbarData     = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
    toolbarGroup    = toolbarData.toolbarFind("actions4");

    toolbarGroup.controls.push(
        {
            type: "TOGGLE",
            action: "maximize-region",
            icon: "fa fa-expand"
        }
    );

    config.initActions = function(actions){
        actions.add({
            name: "maximize-region",
            maximize: false,  
            set: function(maximize) {
                this.maximize = maximize;
                //jQuery to maximize the region would go here
            }, get: function() {
                return this.maximize;
            }
        });
    }

    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    return config;

}



Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What happens if you use next code in Page - Function and Global Variable Declaration:
(function($){
    $(apex.gPageContext$).on("apexreadyend", function(jQueryEvent) {
        $('#IG_STATIC_ID_ig_toolbar').find('.a-Toolbar-group').last().addClass('a-IRR-buttons');
        apex.theme42.page.init();
    });     
})(apex.jQuery);

IG_STATIC_ID to be replaced
your code in "Initialization JavaScript Function" to be disabled
'show maximize button' to be checked on the template options:

Template needs to be 'Interactive Report'
Idea is when it finds the last toolbar group, it adds the 'a-IRR-buttons' class as to mark that toolbar group as a placeholder:

Then the UT init should add the maximize button and attach all needed logic

Maximized:

The relevant UT code is in theme42.js, maximize function.

injectButtonSelector:

adding of the maximize button:

Demo: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/yola/demo/igmaximizebutton

It seems that nothing happens, no errors from what I can tell, but no maximize button either

See edits for some additional comments and screendumps. Tested on 24.1.

running that .find('.a-Toolbar-group').last() from the console command did show me that the a-IRR-buttons class appears to be attached but I do not see the maximize button on my region, Also I'm not super clear on what if any changes to the code were added in the most recent edit.

It might be helpful to include that I will need to customize the Interactive grid's toolbar further at some point in the future via jquery within the region's Initialization JavaScript Function section

No code changes. See edit2. Customizing further should be no issue. There is a quite an amount of code behind the maximize button; see theme42.js maximize function. It also uses widget.toggleCore.js and widget.collapsible.js.

My theme42.js file looks pretty similar to your screenshots, I suppose the version is the issue as my version of APEX is 23.1.0

Looking at the source of 23.1, it should behave the same. I'm not aware of any other approach (apart from using the Std template). Doing it yourself in the IG initialization - I don't see it as feasible. Demo page: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/yola/demo/igmaximizebutton

This solution works perfectly, unfortunately the text wrapping class I applied in the custom attributes field seems to overwrite it

No worries, you can add your text wrapping class via Appearance/CSS classes. You only need to mention the class name over there. It will add then to any existing classes. When you use the Custom Attributes, then it will overwrite existing classes, like the t-IRR-region class which denotes the IG as having the Interactive Report template (the 'maximize' function is testing for that one).

Thank you so much for your help and answering all of my follow-up questions!

I've created https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ideas/details?idea=FR-4080 in APEX ideas app, for full support for the button in APEX IG itself. Kindly cast your vote :-)

Why wouldn't you use built-in maximize button?

set region template to "Standard" (as far as I can tell, it has to be "Standard"; won't work for e.g. "Interactive Report" template, which is default for interactive grids)
edit template options and check the "Show maximize button" checkbox
result is the maximize button (right-hand side of the screenshot)



A few reasons, firstly I find the position of the button to be a bit awkward, i'd like it on the toolbar, secondly the inclusion of that region header eats into the screen space once the region is maximized, and finally, I have a custom CSS class for text wrapping in my region that doesn't seem to work once the template is changed from Interactive Grid to Standard
